# Exceptions in Qt under Windows (mingw)

Tags: qt, exception, static, mingw

I'm writing an application that uses Qt, and I'd like to make it available to Windows users. I'm using mingw. I want to configure Qt with -exceptions as well as -static. Is this possible? I've found a post on a blog that states that static builds with mingw and exceptions will cause memory leaks:
http://blog.lugru.com/2010/04/static-qt-compilation-and-mingwm10-dll-mingw-confusion/

Some of my code throws exceptions, which should be handled in the GUI part of my code by displaying an error dialog (meaning: I don't want to remove all exceptions from my code).

I tried to build Qt with both -static and -exceptions and it didn't seem to work (I still got error messages about exceptions when I tried to compile my code). I won't rule out the possibility that I somehow messed that up, but if these options are mutually exclusive, it would be nice to know before I spend all day compiling Qt again. Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, you should not let any exceptions leak from your code to Qt event loop. That is, if you call a method which may throw an exception, you must catch the exception in your code too (and possibly emit a signal or directly call some generic method to open a dialog window or whatever).

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. But assuming I catch and handle all exceptions, do I still have a problem with mingw, Qt, and static builds?

Comment: You don't need to use the -exceptions configure option to use exceptions in your code.  I do it all the time.  Like hyde said, just don't let exceptions exit your code and you will be fine.

Comment: Great, thanks. In general, it seems that every tutorial/wiki that explains how to do static builds of Qt applications says that it's important to build Qt with -no-exceptions... but that blog entry I mentioned above was the only thing I found that explained why. In the end, I decided to go with a shared library build anyway, but I didn't notice any problems with the static build.